# POWERSHELL: The term 'New-AcceptedDomain' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, exchange-2013

I am trying to set-up a multi tenant exchange 2013 environment.
Currently we have the 2013 environment in production and have a few companies using it.
The drawback however is that each company can see each others addresses due to the single GAL.

I have read, to alleviate this i must set up multi tenancy following the instructions here > https://www.geekandi.com/2013/08/02/exchange-2013-multi-tenancy-step-by-step/

I am stuck at the part where I create a New-AcceptedDomain (see error below)

> PS C:> New-AcceptedDomain -Name "New Tenant 1" -DomainName test.exchange -DomainType:Authoritative
>   New-AcceptedDomain : The term 'New-AcceptedDomain' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, >function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path >is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + New-AcceptedDomain -Name "New Tenant 1" -DomainName test.exchange -DomainType:Au ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>      + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-AcceptedDomain:String) [],CommandNotFoundException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I have attempted to run this shell command on the MB Svr, CA Svr and the AD svr!

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That cmdlet is part of the Exchange 2013 Management Shell.  You need to be in the Exchange Management Shell itself, not a separate PowerShell, to run it.

Comment: No worries, that trips up most Windows guys too.  It's a weird design choice that doesn't seem to have any logical rationale.